# Full width CSS bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't know if columns are responsible of my issue.

**What I have**

My web page is good for small devices (< 768px). But less than 768px there is a `<div class="row">` that seems to be wrong. Look at the picture.

---

**What I would like to**

I would like the list take full width, one by one in a vertical alignment.

---

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <h3 class="uppercase titre-bleu">Pourquoi choisir CEMEX ?</h3>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 englobe-points-fort">
        <div class="row points-fort">
            <h2>1</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 englobe-points-fort">
        <div class="row points-fort">
            <h2>2</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 englobe-points-fort">
        <div class="row points-fort">
            <h2>3</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 englobe-points-fort">
        <div class="row points-fort">
            <h2>4</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 englobe-points-fort">
        <div class="row points-fort">
            <h2>5</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my SCSS :

```
.points-fort{
 h2{
   width: 7%;
   margin-left: 47%;
 }

 p{
   font-size: 17px;
 }
}
```

The good one (768px and up)
[image]

The bad one (less than 768px)
[image]

Comment: you may need to show more HTML code. the overlap between the form and the USPs suggests that there is some floating going on that your `.row` isn't handling properly.

Comment: Actually the code before is a laaarge form so I can't post all of it

Comment: Try posting on a JSfiddle for example

Comment: why are yo using `.row` class inside columns..you are violating bootstraps grid structure..if row class is your custom class try changing it's name..this is what is causing the problem

Comment: I deleted row inside `col` class, but it still doesn't work ..

Comment: please post your entire html and css in a fiddle (i.e. bootply, jsbin, etc.)